# Stream buffer with mailboxes on simgrid/C++

Tags: c++, simgrid

I am a beginner with simgrid and I need to do a task where you must create a stream buffer to send 20 messages between the nodes of a ring, with mailboxes.
I would like help and if possible examples of how I can perform this task.